# SCSS @each nesting colours

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have a series of selectors for colouring up days of the week

I'd like to do;

```
$saturday : blue;
$sunday : green;
...
$friday : red;

$days : saturday, sunday, ... friday;
@each $day in $days {
  .day-{$day}  {
    background: rgba(${$day}, 0.15);
    & .weekday {
      background: ${$day};
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work (won't compile).

Is this kind of nesting simply not possible in SCSS? or is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Can you please show the full code (with colors)? There are multiple mistakes in the code you provided but some might be due to the missing parts...

Comment: @Arkellys Will do. I did decide it was probably easier to write the 20 lines of code rather than persist with this but there is an intellectual interest in the concept of nesting variables in SSCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of your code are a bit unclear so I will assume that what you are trying to do should be more like the following:

```
$days : (
  saturday: blue,
  sunday: green,
  ...
  friday: red
);

@each $day, $color in $days {
  .day-#{$day}  {
    background: rgba($color, 0.15);
    & .weekday {
      background: $color;
    }
  }
}
```

One notable mistake in your code is the bad syntax of your [interpolations](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) which should be write as `#{$variable}` and not `${$variable}` or `{variable}`. Also, it is not required that you interpolate *everything*, you can look at the documentation to get a better understanding about this.

Then, since you need to associate days with colors you should use a [map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) instead of a [list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists). Using the [`@each`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) loop let you access each values so you can use them where you need in the code.

Comment: Thank you.  I was obviously getting (thoroughly) confused with the syntax and the concept of interpolation was new to me so this has given some new clues to approach the documentation.